# How to keybind specific Emmet wrap with abbreviation commands in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, vscode-keybinding

I have been using the [Emmet Wrap with Abbreviation](https://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/) recently and am looking for ways to streamline my process. In particular I am looking for a way to add keybinds for particular Warp abbreviations.

The current process is receiving a plain text sheet of content and then adding HTML structure to it (ie: headings, p tags, divs, anchor tags etc.). Emmet Wrap with Abbreviations are great for this as I can just select the text I want formatted and use the abbreviation to quickly format it, however it would be better if there is some way to add key binds to commonly used elements.

**Some examples:**

- an anchor tag keybind that uses: `a[title][target=_blank]`
- an unordered list keybind that uses: `ul>li*`

Through looking for keybind info in VS Code I know you can add custom keyboard shortcuts by editing the `keybindings.json` file in your user settings. But, I can't figure out how to activate the Emmet Wrap with Abbreviations shortcut and then auto-fill the specific abbreviation I want to use.
Currently my general binding for Wrap with Abbreviation is:

```
{
   "key": "shift+alt+w",
   "command": "editor.emmet.action.wrapWithAbbreviation"
}
```

**How can I add a Keybinding to VS Code, so that when I hit the bound button it runs the Wrap with Abbreviation command with a specific abbreviation?**

Comment: I am about 50/50 right now if the answer to this question is stupid simple, or the feature is not supported. Any help would be appreciated, and let me know if I can provide any more information on what I have found that didn't work or what I am trying to do.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do.  Can you give the before selection, the css wrap, and what you want after the keybinding trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+e",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.wrapWithAbbreviation",
    "when": "editorHasSelection",
    "args": {
        "abbreviation": "li*",
    }
}
```